# Bulk changing font properties

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I have a directory of fonts like so:

```
├── Trenda Black It.ttf
├── Trenda Black.ttf
├── Trenda Bold It.ttf
├── Trenda Bold.ttf
├── Trenda ExtraLight It.ttf
├── Trenda ExtraLight.ttf
├── Trenda Heavy It.ttf
├── Trenda Heavy.ttf
├── Trenda Light It.ttf
├── Trenda Light.ttf
├── Trenda RegularIt.ttf
├── Trenda Regular.ttf
├── Trenda Semibold It.ttf
├── Trenda Semibold.ttf
├── Trenda Thin It.ttf
└── Trenda Thin.ttf
```

Unfortunately, the font families are not all `Trenda`, they are `Trenda Black`, `Trenda Bold` and so on.

Is there a way to automate the process of changing all of the Font-Families to `Trenda`?

Previously I have done it manually on each Font using [Font Forge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) but this takes ages.

It would be great if I was also able to set the Weight Class as well based on the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking, you can interface with font forge in python.

Python is not what I normally program in so appologies for the poor code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fontforge as ff
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]

if args[0] == '--help':
    print("changeFontFamily <font> <family> <newFont>")
else:
    font = args[0]
    family = args[1]
    newfont = args[2]
    f = ff.open( font )
    f.familyname = family
    f.generate(newfont)
```

I then just use this in a bash loop

```
for file in *.ttf; do changeFontFamily "$file" "Trenda" "new/$file" 2> /dev/null; done
```